# How could "sum of exponential distribution is 1" be proven?

Tags: sum, exponential-distribution

$$f(x; \lambda) = \begin{cases} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \quad \text { for } x \geq 0 \\
 0 \quad  \quad  \quad \text { for }x < 0\end{cases}
$$

How can I prove that the sum of probabilities under the exponential distribution is equal to 1?

Comment: You can't -- density is not probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = -e^{-\lambda x}|_0^\infty = 0 + 1 =1$